# What's the study of the social review distribution? (e.g. the book review star distribution on Amazon)

Tags: probability, distributions

I'm not sure if the question title is proper, I just want to know if there is related study on this subject.

For example, for a Amazon book, it will have a review distribution like this

[image]

And it can take many forms, like this one

[image]

or even like this

[image]

I want to know, what distribution is this kind of thing? And if there is any related books, important papers that I can read about? Maybe about its property or anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most logical statistical model is the ordinal logistic or probit. These are widely available. You know how logistic regression models the log of the odds of something happening or not? Ordered logit models the log odds of giving a higher rating.

The ordinal logit model makes the proportional odds assumption, which is that the relationship between each pair of rating is identical, and that the effect of all the covariates you measured is the same across all pairs. There are formal tests for whether or not this assumption is violated (the Brant test is one). If violated, there are some alternative models which make fewer assumptions but estimate more parameters. Get familiar with the ordinal models first, but alternative models include stereotype logit and generalized ordered logistic (and I have not used either of these models, personally).

Comment: Is this really proper? For example, sometimes the mode is at the 4 stars. Is Ordered logit model, 'the odds of giving a higher rating', sufficient to describe when the mode is 4 or 5 stars?

Comment: Yes, it is. The underlying assumption is that there is a latent (unseen) continuous variable, and that the higher that variable, the higher the probability of responding to a certain category. So, the ordered probability models basically estimate cut points of that latent variable that correspond to each category. I am not quite doing the explanation justice, so I suggest you investigate further.